# Selenium, how do you check scroll position

Tags: java, selenium, scroll

Using selenium with java, I need to test a "Back to top" button, so what I did is to scroll page down until "Back to top" button is shown (as it is shown when scrolled 25% of the page) and click it, this button takes user to the top of the page, now I need to check that it worked and the visible part is the top of the page. How can I do this using java?

Answer (score 29):

The general principle is to check the value of `window.pageYOffset` in the browser. If your button scrolls *completely* back to the top then `window.pageYOffset` should have a value of 0. Assuming the `driver` variable holds your `WebDriver` instance:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return window.pageYOffset;");
```

You can then check that `value` is 0. `executeScript` is used to run JavaScript code in the browser.

This answer initially mentioned `scrollY` but there's no support for it on IE. The [MDN page on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY), says:

> For cross-browser compatibility, use `window.pageYOffset` instead of `window.scrollY`. Additionally, older versions of Internet Explorer (< 9) do not support either property and must be worked around by checking other non-standard properties. A fully compatible example:
>
> ```
> var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
> var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");
>
> var x = supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
> var y = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
> ```

Thanks to [R. Oosterholt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1183010/r-oosterholt) for the "heads up".

Comment: hey louis what is the need of the long data-type when the value is 0

Answer (score 9):

Louis' answer works, but is not fully cross-browser compatible, as Internet Explorer does not support window.scrollY. I recommend using window.pageYOffset instead - this returns the same value but is cross-browser compatible.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

Here is the above code block with the modified code:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return window.pageYOffset;");
```

Also, syntax for Ruby (what I use for my current position, assuming as before that the driver instance is accessible through the variable name, 'driver'):

```
driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset;')
```

Answer (score 0):

if necessary, find the position scrolled to one specify div, use this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return document.getElementById('container').scrollTop;");
```