# How to validate the user has been scroll to top when he click on "back to top" button in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I came across one of the scenario where I need to validate the user is scroll to top of the page when clicked on the "back to top" button on the bottom of the screen.

I tried with the following way but that didn't work.

I tried to validate the element present on the top of the page using

```
isDisplayed method
```

I have attached the image for clear description.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium, how do you check scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733877/selenium-how-do-you-check-scroll-position)

Comment: You can execute javascript: executeScript("return window.pageYOffset;")

Comment: Could you please elaborate it how to use Kantu will that work with the web driver

Comment: @Ywapom so if I take the pixel oriented approach what if I am executing it on the higher screens let’s pair programming system or let’s say the System of higher inches screen.

Comment: @khan the system/size shouldn't matter, "back to top" should take you to the browsers  window.pageYoffset of zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using the javascript concept used pageYOffset method.

Complete code

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return window.pageYOffset;");
```

pageYOffset method will return the vertical pixels, so as soon I logged in got the vertical pixels and then scrolled to the back to top button and after performing the action on back to top button, again got the vertical pixels and validated it.

Answer (score 0):

isDisplayed() checks if the element is actually present in the viewport so it should work. May be put some wait in between clicking and checking isDisplayed for debugging puropose .

```
if (element.isDisplayed()) {
doSomething(); 
}
else {
doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: I did even tried with the isDispalyed it doen’t work.when I scrolled to the bottom of the page I did assert with the top most element of the page it returned true

Comment: Can you try the opposite way, if testing permits, to assert the scrollToTop button is not displayed? Does that return true as well?

Comment: Can you elaborate it with the example please

Comment: You have 'Back to Top' which disappears if you reach the top. So was wondering if your test case test the disappearing of the button (which is one way of saying you reached the top of page if it is no longer displayed though not a very good test).

Comment: Yes we do,we can test it.

Comment: disappear in sense it will not be visible on the screen,how do we test the disappearing of the button,I even used invisibilityOfElementLocated method still no use.